# What are the missing numbers?

Tags: logical-deduction, missing-digits

[image: Skeletal Division]

> The question is to find the value(s) of *. All the values may be same or different. for example- one of the * could be 8 while another one could be 4.

P.S. While cleaning my old cupboard, I came across this. This was a puzzle given to me and my friends as a part of some project work some years back. It fascinated us then and now I wanted to share it here. Do try to solve it. It's real fun.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all leading digits are nonzero (for example, the single-digit result of the first subtraction)?

Comment: @2012rcampion If it's not marked, then you can consider it to be 0

Comment: That doesn't answer my question; can stars represent zero as well?  Another example, can the divisor be anything between 0-999, or just 100-999?

Comment: @2012rcampion Yes, stars can represent 0 (But not first stars, for example, 300 is *** not ****) Divisors is 100-999.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is

> Divisor: 199. Dividend: 598000572.  Solution: 3005028

Explanation:

> The first big hint was with line 3 and 4 (calling line 1 the initial equation, and line 9 being 0000)
> xxxx−xxx = 5
> This means line 3 is between 1000 and 1004, so line 4 is between 995 and 999.
> So the divisor is a three-digit number which has a multiple between 995 and 999.
> Using this information, and looking at lines 1 and 2, the divisor must be less than 500. So now our current bounds for the divisor are 100 and 500. And since line 4 (constrained between 995 and 999) is a multiple of our divisor (100 to 500), we generate a list of possible options being...
> 995: 199
> 996: 498, 332, 249, 166
> 997: No options
> 998: 499
> 999: 333
> The difference between the subtraction of line 1 and line 2 is equal to 1, so the possible values of line two are 499 to 598. We then can check to see what options do not have a multiple between this range, removing 498, 332, 249, 333. Which leaves us with 166, 199, 499. 
> Using lines 7 and 8, the second value of each number, must be a 5. So it must be at least 1500. Since 166×9 < 1500, this rules out 166.
> Finally with lines 5 and 6, if you use 499 it is impossible to get a remainder greater than 150, which is required for line 7.
> This leaves only 199 left, so using 199, we get a dividend of 598000572 and an answer of 3005028, which satisfies the conditions of the puzzle.

Here's a picture with all the numbers:

> [image: Solution]

Comment: Excellent.... Nicely done +1.

Comment: Sid, is this a type of puzzle that exists?  Or did you and your friend invent it?  I am very curious here!

Comment: @Topple: I've definitely seen this puzzle before.

Comment: @Topple Well, we didn't invent this puzzle. It was given to us to solve as part of a project work. I think, you can find some of these on the internet...

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a pretty MathJax rendering of the solution
(which I found independently after [slimeArmy’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/38753/19765#38761) was posted).

$$
% Define a very small, pale comma:
 \newcommand{\c}{\hskip{-0.5pt}\large\color{#888},\huge\hskip{-6.5pt}}
% If you want to eliminate the commas, just do
% \newcommand{\c}{}
%
% Define a red "5":
 \newcommand{\5}{\color{#D11}5}
% Change the above definition to change the color of all the fives
% simultaneously and synchronously.
%
% Define a small, unobtrusive minus sign, and underline the following number:
 \newcommand{minus}[1]{^{_{_{_-}}}\underline{#1}}
%
% This is what the MathJax for the long division looks like:
%
% \huge\begin{align}
%                                3\c005\c028 \\
% 199\Huge/\!\huge\overline{\,\598\c000\c572}\\
%                       \minus{597}\phantom{\c000\c000}\\
%                                1000\phantom{\c\c000} \\
%                          \minus{995}\phantom{\c\c000}\\
%                                  \557\phantom{\c\c0} \\
%                            \minus{398}\phantom{\c\c0}\\
%                                   1\592 \\
%                             \minus{1592}\\
%                                       0
% \end{align}
%
% Unfortunately, multi-line MathJax doesn't work in spoiler blocks,
% so I have to do this:
$$

> $$\huge\begin{align}3\c005\c028\\199\Huge/\!\huge\overline{\,\598\c000\c572}\\\minus{597}\phantom{\c000\c000}\\1000\phantom{\c\c000}\\\minus{995}\phantom{\c\c000}\\\557\phantom{\c\c0}\\\minus{398}\phantom{\c\c0}\\1\592\phantom{\c\c}\\\minus{1592}\phantom{\c\c}\\0\phantom{\c\c}\end{align}$$